# Алгоритм получения изменений в файле

Tags: c++, qt5

Нужно с определённой периодичностью проверять изменения в файле и если файл был изменён, то программе нужно считать только это изменение.

Подскажите как правильно, а главное, оптимально по времени и ресурсам это сделать, используя *Qt5*?

P.S. Размер файла может быть разный.

Comment: Файловая система поддерживает обновление времени изменения файла?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если бы вы внимательно читали документацию, то там есть такой функционал.
[QFileSystemWatcher Class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemwatcher.html)

```
...
QFileSystemWatcher watcher;
watcher.addPath("/My/Path/To/The/File");

QObject::connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(fileChanged(const QString&)), receiver, SLOT(handleFileChanged(const QString&)));
...
```